# ListViewの中にTextViewを入れてAdapterで値を紐づけようとすると実行に失敗する

Tags: android, xml

以下の通りにAdapterとactivity_main.xmlを記述しています。
コメントアウトしてあるところを有効にすると、実行に失敗します。

MainActivity.java内にメソッドをたくさん書いていますが、
AdapterをListViewに設定するところで落ちたり、
onCreateのsetContentView(R.layout.activity_main);で落ちたりしています。

英語で調べましたが独学で限界です。

何かわかる方いらっしゃったらよろしくお願い致します。

---

**BoolAndDateAdapter.java**

```java
public class BoolAndDateBeanAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public BoolAndDateBeanAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    ArrayList<BoolAndDateBean> beans;

    public void setBeans(ArrayList<BoolAndDateBean> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return beans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return beans.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent);

    //        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bool)).setText(String.valueOf(beans.get(position).bool));
    //        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hour)).setText(beans.get(position).hour);
    //        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minit)).setText(beans.get(position).minit);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textOff="off"
                android:textOn="on"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="OnClick_Add"
                app:rippleColor="#00FCFCFC"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="1">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2">
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="3"></Button>
            </GridLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/grid">
                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/bool"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="50dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="50dp"/>-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/hour"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="50dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="50dp"/>-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/minit"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="50dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="50dp"/>-->
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListViewの中に別のViewを入れていたことが原因でした。解決しました。